# how to set image resource of TouchImageView with url instead of drawable

Tags: android, touchimageview

I have this code that works with an image in the drawable resource and was wandering how I would rewrite it for an url image:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MultiTouchActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TouchImageView img = new TouchImageView(this);
        img.setImageResource(R.map);
        img.setMaxZoom(6f);
        setContentView(img);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to download the remote image yourself.

You could do it manually:

```
new AsyncTask {
    Bitmap doInBackground(Void[] params) {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(image_url).openStream();
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
    };

   void onPostExecute(Bitmap bmp) {
       imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);           }
   }
}.execute();
```

Or use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and get the benefit of simplicity and local caching:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Other libs that do a decent job in downloading and caching remote images:

- [Universal Image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
- [Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)
- [Novoda’s Image loader](https://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader)